# What are the best practices to include static content with Jsp?

Tags: jsp, static, web, jsp-fragments

What are the best practices to include static content in a Java web application?

I'm thinking about `html`, another `jsp`, `jspf`.

If any of you have other ideas/recommandations, can you detail your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

There a few typos in what you are writing (or understanding). First, I do not think there is a general best practice in including static content:

Sure, you can have servlets or JSP files with static content (although sounds a bit ridiculous), but why so? Second, you are thinking wrong about HTML. HTML is a language, it is not an static content.

HTML "pages" may be static or dynamic but that is irrelevant as well. JSPF is a more or less depreciated library and was not updated from last May, so it is not a best practice at all!

I think you just need to focus on what you want, how to write them and how to write questions for things you want but already do not know them.